# LeetCode 7: Reverse Integer | why does it work with a long but not with an int?

Tags: java, integer, reverse, long-integer

I was trying to solve [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-integer/) problem on LeetCode where you have to reverse an integer using a function. The constraint is that if the reversed number goes outside the signed 32-bit integer range, i.e. (-2^31) to (2^31 - 1) then you return 0. When I use an integer for the reversed variable like this

```
class Solution { 
        public int reverse(int x) {
            int rev = 0;
            while (x != 0) {
                rev = rev * 10 + x % 10;
                x /= 10;
            }

            if((rev > Integer.MAX_VALUE) || (rev < Integer.MIN_VALUE))
                return 0;

            return rev;
        }
}
```

IntelliJ IDEA shows that the

```
Condition 'rev > Integer.MAX_VALUE' is always 'false'
```

However, when I use a long instead of int, the problem is resolved and the program works as you would expect.

```
class Solution {
        public int reverse(int x) {
            long rev = 0;
            while (x != 0) {
                rev = rev * 10 + x % 10;
                x /= 10;
            }

            if((rev > Integer.MAX_VALUE) || (rev < Integer.MIN_VALUE))
                return 0;

            return (int)rev;
        }
}
```

I was wondering why is that the case?

Comment: Because when `rev` is an `int` it literally cannot be greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. The other condition is also impossible. Because it is an `int`. That's like asking for one value greater than the greatest possible value. Or one value less than the least possible value. With a `long` it is possible to have a value greater than the greatest possible `int` value. Or less than the least possible `int` value. `long` is 64-bits.

Answer (score 0):

In the first code block, `rev` is an integer. Thus, it is impossible for it to be *greater* than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` - the maximum value for an integer.

With a `long`, it is possible to have a value greater than the greatest possible `int` value. A Java `int` is a signed 32-bit value. A Java `long` is a signed 64-bit value.

Answer (score 0):

For me this works...

```
class Solution {
    public int reverse(int x) {
        int mod = 0, rev = 0;
            while(x!=0){
                if(rev < Integer.MIN_VALUE/10 || rev > Integer.MAX_VALUE/10){
                return 0;
                }
            mod = x%10;
            x = x/10;
            rev = rev*10 + mod;
            }
            return rev;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution:
  def reverse(self, x: int) -> int:
    check_num = str(x)
    flag = 0
    if(check_num[0] == '-'):
        check_num = check_num[1:]
        flag = 1

    #print(check_num)

    #reverse
    time = len(check_num)
    storage = [0] * time 
    for i in range(len(check_num)):
        num = len(check_num)-i-1
        storage[i] = check_num[num]
        #print(storage[i])

    if(flag == 1):
        storage.insert(0, '-')

    #turn to string
    oneLinerString=""
    for x in storage:
        oneLinerString += x

    ans = int(oneLinerString)  # removes leading zeros in the reversed string

    if not -2**31 <= ans <= 2**31 - 1:
        return 0

    return ans
```

Try this code Using Python 3 format at Leetcode you will passed..

Answer (score 0):

In Java, the int data type is a 32-bit signed integer, which means it can hold values from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647. If rev exceeds this range, it will overflow and wrap around to the minimum value, which is -2,147,483,648. Therefore, the condition rev > Integer.MAX_VALUE will never be true.